# OTP14B02 configure error

Tags: erlang, mnesia, erlang-otp, yaws, nitrogen

I have tried to install OTP14B02 on OpenSolaris and i get the following error at calling `./configure`:

```
muzaaya@opensolaris:~/Desktop/software and data/otp_src_R14B02# ./configure 
Ignoring the --cache-file argument since it can cause the system to be erroneously configured
Disabling caching
Usage: cd [-LP] [directory]
   Or: cd [ options ] old new
configure: error: cannot find install-sh or install.sh in 
export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software and data/otp_src_R14B02/erts/autoconf 
/export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software and 
data/otp_src_R14B02//export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software and data/otp_src_R14B02/erts/autoconf
```

What could be causing this problem and how can i overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I see a space in a path on any system all kinds of bells an whistles goes off, it shouldn't matter but sometime it does. Have you tried moving to a path without spaces in it?

Also, as it says, it failed to find /export/home/muzaaya/Desktop/software and data/otp_src_R14B02/erts/autoconf/install.sh, does that file exist on your system?

Comment: Thanks Lukas, renaming the folder helped!